# Eclipse javascript character encoding

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, character-encoding, jstl

I'd like to display some language specific characters from javascript but I can't.

My app is a Java webapp and the front end is jQuery. All the characters that are sended from the server - in a JSP or with AJAX - are displayed properly. When I want to display some text hardcoded in to the javascript file it's broken.

I'm using Eclipse. In the JSP's header I use:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

I've tried this (charset in the script element) too:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"><c:import url="/JS/mainJS.js" /></script>
```

In my Eclipse I've set the project properties / text file encoding to UTF-8 AND I've checked the JS files' resource properties / text file encoding that is UTF-8 too.

But when I try this:

```
$.test = function(){
    var s = "éééáááűűűű";
    alert(s);
}
```

I get:

```
Ã©Ã©Ã©Ã¡Ã¡Ã¡Å±Å±Å±Å±
```

The strange thing is that: When I try in a separate html file (in the same project), It's working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {background: #c0c0c0;}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var s = "éááűűúúú";
            $("#console").text(s);
            alert(s);
        })
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
        <div id="console"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Even if I DO NOT use any content type and page encoding settings.

What is the problem? What shall I do? (I'm using Apache Tomcat integrated in Eclipse)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using any filter that handles the html? what happens if you use the script tag to import the js file instead of c:import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `c:import` uses the server platform default encoding if the encoding is absent in the response header of the request. Rather just use `src` attribute instead. The webbrowser is smarter in this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/mainJS.js"></script>
```

(if necessary remove the leading slash if you're running on a fixed context instead of on domain root)

If you really, really need the `c:import` for this (for which I honestly don't see *any* advantage in this particular situation), then you need to write a `Filter` listening on `/JS/*` which sets the appropriate `Content-Type` header with the correct encoding on the response. This however won't work if it concerns an external URL, it's then the responsibility of the external server.